# Can't override default of CalendarItem FontFamily in WPF Calendar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to extend the Calendar control into my own that has some dependency properties for setting things like the hover colors, highlight of the current day, and so on. I've got all of my properties and hook them up using bindings, but for some reason, the text displayed for the day of the week heading will not change its font color or style. At first I thought it was my bindings because I'm using a RelativeSource and finding the ancestor type, but I then tried setting them explicitly in the DataTemplate but nothing works.

Is this an inheritance issue from the Calendar base? Or is there something going on internally that's overriding my template? Here's my DataTemplate for the CalendarItem:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Static CalendarItem.DayTitleTemplateResourceKey}">
      <TextBlock Foreground="Red"
                 FontWeight="Bold"
                 FontSize="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CalendarControl}}"
                 FontFamily="Arial"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Margin="0,6,0,6"
                 Text="{Binding}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</DataTemplate>
```

The way I understand it from here, this DataTemplate is used to dynamically generate items for these which are then inserted into the "PART_MonthView" grid below:

```
<Grid x:Name="PART_MonthView"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
      TextElement.FontFamily="Arial"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      Margin="6,-1,6,6"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Visibility="Visible">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Is this DataTemplate even the right template? When you view the control in runtime and use snoop to browse the visual tree, you can see the text blocks being inserted into the grid but the values are coming from a local source:

[image]

I'm stumped and can't find any concrete answers on how to style this stuff. Am I better off building my own UI and then just watching property values to see if they change? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following page from MSDN describes the XAML for styling a calendar in full:
[Calendar Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468218%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

By modifying the value for the `FontSize`, `FontWeight`, and `FontFamily` attributes in the `ControlTemplate` for `CalendarItem` it is possible to modify the font appearance.

Here is an after picture with the font size bumped up to 16.
[image]

I think this is the easiest way to do you what you want. Make a new `ControlTemplate` for `Calendar` using the XAML from the example and then make your alterations.

Comment: Nick, this is exactly what I'm already doing. I agree, it _should_ work, but for whatever reason, it's not. It doesn't matter whether it's a binding to a property or an explicit value, it's still getting overridden from a local source.

I'm not sure if it's because I'm creating a new control, then inheriting from calendar or not. Unfortunately, it has to be a control so that users can access this without any additional work.